# How to Check value id from Tag Input and remove count row is 0?

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

Help me please on this jquery:
I want remove row if value is '0'
but until now on this code, I Just can remove all

```js
$('#refresh').click(function(){
    var tableDestination = $('#example');
    var countTable = tableDestination.length;

    for(var i = 1; i <= countTable; ++i) {
        $('.checklist').each(function(i) {
            var value = $('.checklist').eq(i).val();  

            if (value != 1) {
                //Test Run PerRow
                alert('DeleteValue=' + value + ' ' + 'RowValue=' + i);
                $('tr#DelRow').remove(i);
            }
            else{
                alert('HoldValue=' + value + ' ' + 'RowValue=' + i);
            }
        });

        $('tr#DelRow').remove(i);
    }
});
```

I'm using switch case LIKE

```js
switch(value){
case '0':
    //Test Run PerRow
    alert('DeleteValue=' + value + ' ' + 'RowValue=' + i);
    break;
case '1':
    //Test Run PerRow
    alert('HoldValue=' + value + ' ' + 'RowValue=' + i);
    break;
}
```

I want keep the green checklist
and red cross to remove

**this is Result** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMocu.png

Comment: I think the question can probably be clearer.  What is at #tableDestination and what does the data look like?

Comment: the #tableDestination is Table id and the data look like http://i.stack.imgur.com/jMocu.png  @Kolban

Comment: In your initial question, you say you want to remove a row if the value is '0'.  The value of what?  The value of which column?

Comment: @Kolban you can seen the picture the value '0' and '1' put in Tag <input type="hidden" id="checklist" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" id="checklist" value="1"/>
the value on the last coloum like checklist and cross

Comment: anybody cant help me ???

Comment: I think the desire to help is present but it is likely that the community doesn't understand the question.  Maybe you can create a jsFiddle showing the whole thing and describe your puzzle in terms of that?

Comment: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/CRTL/t1L2z4fv/1/ @Kolban this is my link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will remove all rows from a table which have a column that contains an `<input>` element that has a `value` of `0`.  It is executed when a button on the page is clicked.  A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1L2z4fv/14/) is provided to illustrate.

```
$(function () {
    $('#refresh').click(function () {
        $("#example tr:has(input[value='0'])").remove();
    });
});
```

The core of the work is in the jQuery selector which is `#example tr:has(input[value='0'])`.  The way to read this is:

- Find the element in the page with an `id` of `example`.  This will be the table.
- Find all the `tr` (table row) children of the table which contain an `input` element that has a property `value` of `0`.

When we have the list, we execute the jQuery [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove them from the DOM.